# Values of selected options in dynamic h:selectManyListbox dont change

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm creating dynamic h:selectManyListbox(es) using c:forEach but it seems that when I select different options from the h:selectManyListbox, the value corresponding to the selected options doesn't change. Here is my code. Please help I'm new with JSF 2.

This is my xhtml section (#{item.selectedBranches} not updated when options are selected) :

```
<h:body>
Hi
<h:form id="hehe">

    <c:forEach items="#{branchesController.dynamicListBoxBean}" var="item"   >






        <h3>  <h:outputLabel value="#{item.category}"/> </h3>


        <h:selectManyListbox size="20" style="width: 300px" value="#{item.selectedBranches}"  id="#{item.category}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{item.specificBranches}" >

        </f:selectItems>


    </h:selectManyListbox>



          </c:forEach>



</h:form>

</h:body>
```

This is my Controller Code :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "branchesController")
@RequestScoped
public class BranchesController implements Serializable {

@EJB
private entities.BranchesFacade ejbFacade;
private List<Branches> items = null;
private List<Branches> selectedItems = null;


private List<DynamicListBoxBean> dynamicListBoxBean = new ArrayList<>();

public BranchesController() {

}


private BranchesFacade getFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
}



public List<Branches> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getFacade().findAll();
    }
    return items;
}

public List<DynamicListBoxBean> getDynamicListBoxBean() {
    List<Branches> a = new ArrayList<>();
    a= getFacade().findAll();
   /* a.set(0, new Branches("1","Bib","Small"));
    a.set(1, new Branches("2","Bob","Small"));
    a.set(2, new Branches("3","jbb","Small"));*/
       List<Branches> s = new ArrayList<>();
       s = getFacade().findAll();
      /* s.set(0, new Branches("1","Bib","Small"));
    s.set(1, new Branches("2","Bob","Small"));
    s.set(2, new Branches("3","jbb","Small"));*/
       DynamicListBoxBean x = new DynamicListBoxBean("Small",0,a,s);
       List<DynamicListBoxBean> abc = new ArrayList<DynamicListBoxBean>();
       abc.add(0, x);

    dynamicListBoxBean = abc;


    return dynamicListBoxBean;
}

public void setDynamicListBoxBean(List<DynamicListBoxBean> 
dynamicListBoxBean) {
    this.dynamicListBoxBean = dynamicListBoxBean;
}



@FacesConverter(forClass = Branches.class)
public static class BranchesControllerConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent 
    component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        BranchesController controller = (BranchesController) 
        facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, 
        "branchesController");
        return controller.getFacade().find(getKey(value));
    }

    java.lang.String getKey(String value) {
        java.lang.String key;
        key = value;
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(java.lang.String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(value);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent 
    component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof Branches) {
            Branches o = (Branches) object;
            return getStringKey(o.getId());
        } else {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
    "object {0} is of type {1}; expected type: {2}", new Object[]{object, 
    object.getClass().getName(), Branches.class.getName()});
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

this is my Branches class :

```
public class Branches implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "ID")
private String id;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "CATEGORY")
private String category;

public Branches() {
}

public Branches(String id, String name, String category) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.category = category;
}
```

And finally this is my DynamicListBoxBean :

```
public class DynamicListBoxBean {
private String category;
private int cbValue;
private List<Branches> specificBranches;
private List<Branches> selectedBranches;

public DynamicListBoxBean(String category, int cbValue, List<Branches> 
    specificBranches, List<Branches> selectedBranches) {
    this.category = category;
    this.cbValue = cbValue;
    this.specificBranches = specificBranches;
    this.selectedBranches = selectedBranches;
}

With gettters and setters ...
```

I really dont understand what's happening.. Shouldn't the item.selectedBranches points to the property in the managedbean ?

Comment: Without digging in the code: If you are talking about "dynamic Listboxes" - a `@RequestScoped` bean seems wrong. This bean will be recreated upon every (ajax-)request. Try to use `@ViewScope` to make sure the beans are maintaining their state as long as the view lives. Don't forget that `ViewScoped` beans have to be serializable. (As well as their included properties, regardless if they are primitives or objects.)

Comment: With @ViewScoped nothing appears except the button